# Excel - Split data by a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given the below example, I have a data set, and I want the data set to be grouped by x decrements of 5. How can I accomplish this?

...

[image: Example]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF07s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy with a *Helper column*.  Starting with data in columns **A** and **B** like:

[image]

In **E1** enter 1 and in **E2** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,0,1+MAX($E$1:E1))
```

and copy downwards. *(Column **E** is the helper)*

In  **C1** enter:

```
=IF($E1=0,"",INDEX(A:A,$E1))
```

and copy downward.  Then copy column **C** into column **D**:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for the answer. I've revised the question, and am having difficulty adapting your solution to the new question. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pivot could help you with that?
The table would look little different than what you present but it's the only thing I can think of.

Insert `y` column in Rows and `x` 2 times in values. As aggregate use one min and one max.